# Mongoose -- current URL string parser is deprecated, despite passing option { useNewUrlParser: true }

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Started getting this error after switching from mongoose.connect to mongoose.createConnection in order to be able to implement photo uploads. Anyone know why this deprecation is being thrown?

```
const connectDB = async () => {

    try {
        const conn = await mongoose.createConnection(db, {
            useNewUrlParser: true,
            useUnifiedTopology: true,
            useCreateIndex: true
        });

        let gfs;

        conn.once('open', () => {
            gfs = Grid(conn.db, mongoose.mongo);
            gfs.collection('uploads');
        })

        console.log('MongoDB Connected');
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
        process.exit(1)
    }
};
```

Below is where the problem is stemming. Something in the GridFsStorage is throwing the deprecation.

```
const storage = new GridFsStorage({ url: db });
const upload = multer({ storage });
```

Comment: what is db here? as far as I can tell it shouldn't throw any error. I am assuming db is your connection string? What version of mongo and mongoose are you using?

Comment: db is the Mongo URI string. I am using mongoose - 5.7.1 @AshishModi

Comment: Just edited the question as well. Found the stem of the problem but not yet the solution. @AshishModi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass `useNewUrlParser: true` when you are doing `const storage = new GridFsStorage({ url: db });`

Basiclaly

```
const storage = new GridFsStorage({ url: db, "options": {useNewUrlParser: true}});
```

Comment: Awesome. Thank you very much. However, it seems as if I am unable to access my original connection when I upload to GridFsStorage bucket. Do you have any clue what may be happening? @AshishModi

Comment: for that I would suggest to open a new question with more details. Feel free to mark it as answer for other people's reference.